# React Native trying to create a border for text

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a "box" for a text - meaning a bounding box with border & background color for a text (in my case, a single character).
But when I create a view & text, the text is being cut by the upper bound of the view (look how the *A* is cut), and I cannot understand why.
[My current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enMO1.png)

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
 <Text style={styles.letter} > {character} </Text>
 </View >

export default EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',

  },
  letter: {
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
    borderWidth: 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderColor: 'steelblue',
  },
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `margin` style to `letter` and `aligSelf: 'center'`, but actually I'd recommend adding `backgroundColor` and `borderWidth` to `<View>` styles

Answer (score 0):

Remove the border styles from the text and add them to the view.

https://snack.expo.io/HJAihyR9B

Answer (score 0):

Try adding flex: 1 inside style of the view.

Comment: did you try flex: 1 in the text style component? if that doesn't work can you try the same code you provided in StyleSheet instead of EStyleSheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add padding as i did in below code :

```
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',

  },
  letter: {
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
    borderWidth: 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderColor: 'steelblue',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```